# Accessing Localhost and Virtualhost From Emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I want to access localhost from android studio emulator or from genymotion without typing the IP address instead typing as localhost or as domain name.
If you are into web development you could under stand more like we assign domain for IP in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in windows system.
I tried out steps from some blogs but couldn't figure it out.

Please do help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try editing the hosts file from terminal of the android studio.

First go to terminal and launch the emulator
`emulator -avd AVDNAME -partition-size 128`

Second remount the AVD to make it writable
`adb remount`

Third pull the host file from emulator to your local machine
`adb pull /etc/hosts`

Fourth edit the host file using local editor based on the need
`198.0.0.1 localhost`

Finally, push the edited file from local machine back to emulator `adb push hosts /etc/hosts`

Now, type localhost or domain you assigned in the host file.

Hope this is enough!

Comment: Thanks for your time.!

Answer (score 1):

Use ip 10.0.2.2 to connect the client app on an emulator with a server running on the same pc as the emulator does.

Answer (score 0):

when you type localhost on emulator, it will point to emulator itself. hosts file in android/linux machines will be under /etc/hosts. try editing the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to access folder within the OS?

Comment: to access these files you need to have a rooted emulator/device. use a filemanager app like es file explorer and open the file. else use adb push pull commands